# Cannot install or remove anything from terminal

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

----Update----
I cannot delete anything, what don't you guys get by this. I can't remove anything. I can't get rid of any of the old kernals. It says "linux-image-extra-3.16.0-51-generic" is needed and It won't let me even install it.

----Problem----
I accidentally turned on Orca and wanted to remove it. Sadly is doesn't let me, and then I tried to free up space on /boot to remove header and it would not let me.

I cannot remove anything.

Output

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-orca

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-image-extra-3.16.0-51-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-51-generic but it is not going to be installed
linux-image-generic-lts-utopic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-51-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then I tried to do the solution it gave me

```
sudo apt-get -f install

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-generic-lts-utopic linux-headers-3.16.0-53
  linux-headers-3.16.0-53-generic linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic
  linux-image-3.16.0-51-generic linux-image-3.16.0-53-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-53-generic linux-image-generic-lts-utopic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-lts-utopic-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.16.0-53 linux-headers-3.16.0-53-generic
  linux-image-3.16.0-51-generic linux-image-3.16.0-53-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-53-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic-lts-utopic linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic
  linux-image-generic-lts-utopic
3 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 140 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 79.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 325 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-image-3.16.0-53-generic amd64 3.16.0-53.72~14.04.1 [16.2 MB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-image-extra-3.16.0-53-generic amd64 3.16.0-53.72~14.04.1 [37.6 MB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-generic-lts-utopic amd64 3.16.0.53.44 [1,806 B]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-image-generic-lts-utopic amd64 3.16.0.53.44 [2,282 B]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-headers-3.16.0-53 all 3.16.0-53.72~14.04.1 [9,055 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-headers-3.16.0-53-generic amd64 3.16.0-53.72~14.04.1 [708 kB]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic amd64 3.16.0.53.44 [2,274 B]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-image-3.16.0-51-generic amd64 3.16.0-51.69~14.04.1 [16.2 MB]
Fetched 79.8 MB in 5s (13.5 MB/s)                         
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-3.16.0-53-generic.
(Reading database ... 524809 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.16.0-53-generic_3.16.0-53.72~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.16.0-53-generic (3.16.0-53.72~14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-53-generic_3.16.0-53.72~14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-53-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-53-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                          dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-53-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-53-generic
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-53-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-extra-3.16.0-53-generic_3.16.0-53.72~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-extra-3.16.0-53-generic (3.16.0-53.72~14.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-generic-lts-utopic_3.16.0.53.44_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic-lts-utopic (3.16.0.53.44) over (3.16.0.51.42) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-generic-lts-utopic_3.16.0.53.44_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic-lts-utopic (3.16.0.53.44) over (3.16.0.51.42) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.16.0-53.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-3.16.0-53_3.16.0-53.72~14.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-3.16.0-53 (3.16.0-53.72~14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.16.0-53-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-3.16.0-53-generic_3.16.0-53.72~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-3.16.0-53-generic (3.16.0-53.72~14.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic_3.16.0.53.44_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic (3.16.0.53.44) over (3.16.0.51.42) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.16.0-51-generic_3.16.0-51.69~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.16.0-51-generic (3.16.0-51.69~14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-51-generic_3.16.0-51.69~14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/abi-3.16.0-51-generic' to '/boot/abi-3.16.0-51-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                          dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-51-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-51-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-51-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-51-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-53-generic_3.16.0-53.72~14.04.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-51-generic_3.16.0-51.69~14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Trying to remove it, the same error pop up as the first block. Tried to install the packages, same error pops up as the first block.

I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: Could you give a bit more information as to what didn't work in the duplicate question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)?